# Selenium Webdriver using Java(Eclipse IDE)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have automated a web app using seleinium webdriver in Eclipse IDE. I am picking the login credential(other dynamic parameters) from one properties file.The automation is working perfectly fine. Now if I want to run the automation in a different machine with different credential.
Could anyone please guide me on how to create the jar file and run it in a different machine.I should be able to change the parameter as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of property file You can keep Your parameters in testNG xml
   file. Even for each and every test also you can configure different
   parameters. Refer : [**Testng Parameter help document**](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters)
2. And For executing in remote machine You have to look at 'Remote
   webdriver' in selenium. [**Selenium Remote Webdriver help document**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/remote.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can read the property file using the below command
String propertyFileLocation = System.getProperty("property.file.location");

pass the value for "property.file.location" from the command prompt.

You can call your jar file as 
java -cp jarfilelocation -Dproperty.file.location=  classlocation

Right click on the project and export it as jar file.

Hope this helps